# Java: Restricting visibility in large projects

Tags: java, visibility

How can I manage (=restrict) visibility in large Java projects?

More specifically:
Given the features "Big-A", "Big-B", some sub-features "Little-A-1", "Little-A-2" and some sub-sub-features "Tiny-A-1-I" and "Tiny-A-1-II". With the "Little-A-*" features being sub-features of "Big-A" and the "Tiny-A-1-*" features being sub-features of "Little-A-1".
There are classes and methods in "Little-A-1" which need to be visible for its enclosing feature "Big-A" and all its (sub-)sub-features, but not for "Big-B". Other classes and methods should only be visible for "Little-A-1" and its sub-features, but not for "Big-A" and not for "Little-A-2". And of course "Tiny-A-1-I" has classes and methods, too, which should only be visible within "Tiny-A-1-I" but not for "Tiny-A-1-II", or only within "Little-A-1" and its sub-features, but not for "Little-A-2" and so on.

In short: I have a large hierarchy of features and need to restrict visibility to parts of that hierarchy. How can this be done in Java, given that the built-in visibilities are not powerful enough for that?

Is there any Java built-in feature that can be used for that? Or any external project? (Or an Eclipse plugin, at least?) I looked at Annotation processors, but it seems they are not powerful enough, too, as they have no access to the actual code. Only to its static structure. Given that Java is used for many big projects, I guess there has to be some solution to that problem. I am probably not the only one having that problem.

The ideal solution would allow me to apply it step wise feature by feature and not require that I have to adapt all the code at once, as that is not possible for me. (Lack of time and resources.) And integration into Eclipse (showing errors when an invisible element is accessed) would be nice, too. :-)

Comment: Are you aware of OSGi?

Comment: Would it be fair to say you want an access level between public and protected where objects from package `foo.bar` could access methods in package `foo`? I have often wanted that

Comment: This is being developed for a future Java version - perhaps in Java 9. See: [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/). For now, I'd go with OSGi.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Yes, that would be the best solution. I know that from Scala and love it. (I'm aware that packages do officially not nest in Java.)

Comment: @Ray: Yes, I've heard of it. But it sounds like a bit of overkill for that particular problem. I'm hoping for a more lightweight solution.

Comment: a lightweight solution would be to program to interfaces and use factories to look up implementations, which are kept package-private. (i expect you know that already, but addressing in the question why that wouldn't work for you might help to narrow this question down.)